# How to sort data in a Spinner

Tags: database, sorting, spinner

I have a number of spinners that are populated from database tables. I would like to control how the data is sorted in the spinner as in one example I have data in the form of:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 etc

but this gets sorted by the spinner like this:

1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,21 etc

obviously not right!

An example of my Spinner code (not the above Spinner though) shown below:

```
    Cursor componentCursor = rmDbHelper.fetchAllComponents();
    startManagingCursor(componentCursor);

    // create an array to specify which fields we want to display
    String[] from2 = new String[]{RMDbAdapter.COMPONENT_FORM_TEXT};
    //INSPECTOR_NAME = "inspector_name"
    // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
    int[] to2 = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    // create simple cursor adapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter componentSpinnerAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, componentCursor, from2, to2 );
    componentSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    // get reference to our spinner
    componentSpinner.setAdapter(componentSpinnerAdapter);
    if (locationId > 0) { // Set spinner to match saved data in database

        int spinnerPosition = 0; 

        for (int i = 0; i < componentSpinner.getCount(); i++)  
        { 
             Cursor cur = (Cursor)(componentSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i)); 

             //--When your bind you data to the spinner to begin with, whatever columns you 
             //--used you will need to reference it in the cursors getString() method... 

             //--Since "getString()" returns the value of the requested column as a String--  
             //--(In my case) the 4th column of my spinner contained all of my text values  
             //--hence why I set the index of "getString()" method to "getString(3)" 

             String componentSpinnerString = cur.getString(2).toString(); 

             if(componentSpinnerString.equals(componentSpinnerData.toString())) 
             { 
                //--get the spinner position-- 
                spinnerPosition = i; 
                break; 
              } 
         }       
        componentSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition); 
    }

    else { // Set spinner to default

        int spinnerPosition = 0; 

        for (int i = 0; i < componentSpinner.getCount(); i++)  
        { 
            Cursor cur = (Cursor)(componentSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i));

            String componentSpinnerString = cur.getString(2).toString();

            if(componentSpinnerString.equals("Upright (front)"))
            { 
                //--get the spinner position-- 
                spinnerPosition = i; 
                break; 
            } 
         }       
        componentSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);

    }
```

The database code below (as requested by gotuskar):

```
public Cursor fetchAllComponents() {
    return rmDb.query(COMPONENT_TABLE, new String[] {
            COMPONENT_ID, RACKING_SYSTEM, COMPONENT_FORM_TEXT, TEXT_BOXES_DATA},
            null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Your values are considered as `String` types, and hence the result.

Comment: Ok gotuskar, thanks for the information.  Any advice with how to get round this as I do have a word in the list as well as numbers..  One way I guess is to use 01,02,03,04,05 etc, but was hoping to avoid this..

Comment: _String componentSpinnerString = cur.getString(2).toString();_ perhaps you would like to do Integer.parseInt(componentSpinnerString) and make integer comparisons?

Comment: @Scamparelli: I don't see the code where you are doing fetching the spinner entries from database. Does your query do the sorting? This piece of code just populates the spinner (as per my understanding).

Comment: @Anshu - I also have text the text 'not applicable' in this spinner, so parsing it won't work.  Gotuskar - rmDbHelper.fetchAllComponents() is where the data is being fetched (in my database helper class).  I have decided to keep with the format 01,02,03 etc..

Comment: @Scamparelli - Can you update the post with code from your DB helper, specifically the query to fetch the data and your POJO that you are populating.

Comment: @gotuskar - I have updated the post to include the query.  Is this what you wanted to see?